# The digits of a positive

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

The digits of positive integer having $3$ digits are in A.P and their sum is $15$. The number obtained by reversing the digits is $594$ less than the original number. Find the number.

My Attempt ;

Let the $3$ digit number be $100x+10y+z$ where $x$,$y$ and $z$ are at hundredth, tenth and ones places respectively.

According to question;

$100x+10y+z=15$

Now,
 what should I do next?

Comment: Quote:´"...are in A.P..." What does it mean ?

Comment: @Callculus, I guess it means the digits are in A.P...

Comment: That information helps.

Comment: @Callculus, I just guess, not sure?   However, the answer is $852$

Comment: It is true that the answer is $852$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y,z$ are in $AP$ then $\frac{x+z}{2}=y$

$AP$ means arithmetic progression. The differences between $x$ and $y$ and  $y$ and $z$ are equal. For more information see [here](http://www.careerbless.com/aptitude/qa/sequence_series_imp.php).

The equation for the sum of the digits is $x+y+z=15$.

And finally we can take up your idea for the last condition:

$100x+10y+z=100z+10y+x+594$

The reversed number is 594 less than the origin number. Thus we have to add 594 to get an equality.

Comment: Could you please tell me abit more? I couldn't understand

Comment: What do you not understand ? Please be a little more specific.

Comment: You got. $(x+y)/2=Y$ but where do you want this to be used?

Comment: No it is $(x+\color{red}z)/2=y$. Now you have three variables and three equations. This little equation system has one unique solution. Can you solve it ?

Comment: I could not understand the question and answers. Too

Comment: Suppose the digits of the number are x,y,z, like YOU have defined. Do you  understand why x+y+z=15 ?

Comment: Yes, x+y+z=15 because the question says the sum of the digits is 15.  But I didn't understand the last condition

Comment: It is clear why the origin number is 100x+10y+z ?

Comment: Yes.  now I got to the point.  Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Fine. You´re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

According to question: $x+y+z=15$. Can you go on from there?

Comment: it's $x+y+z=15$ or $100x+10y+z=15$.   Could you please explain me about that?

Comment: The problem says the sum of the digits is 15. Not the number is 15. The number cannot be 15 since it's a 3-digit number.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\begin{cases}x+y+z=15\\100z+10y+x=100x+10y+z+594\end{cases}$$ so you get $$z-x=6\Rightarrow 2x+y=9$$ The possibilities come from
$$\begin{cases}y\in\{1,3,5,7,9\}\\2x\in\{2,4,6,8\}\end{cases}$$ The three solutions are 
$$N\in \{177,258,339\}$$